# I am trying to use AWS SES Query API GET requests. What is the service name for AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to generate a Signature Version 4, for use in an AWS-SES Query API GET request.  I am trying to generate a 'String to sign', and part of the variables required is the name of the service I am trying to access.  I have looked through the documentation and cannot find the answer to the following question: What is the service name of AWS-SES?  is it 'email', 'SES'?

```
 StringToSign =
Algorithm + \n +
RequestDateTime + \n +
CredentialScope + \n +
HashedCanonicalRequest

CredentialScope  = 20150830/ue-west-1/ServiceName/aws4_request\n
```

Comment: Please note, the region in CredentialScope appears to be misspelled.Should be `eu-west-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Signature Version 4 Signing Process » Changes in Signature Version 4
Changes in Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_changes.html)

> Service name information as a lowercase alphanumeric string (for
>   example, iam). Use the service name that is part of the service's
>   endpoint. For example, the IAM endpoint is https://iam.amazonaws.com,
>   so you use the string iam as part of the Credential parameter.

Checking [Amazon SES Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints), we can see the list of SES end points:

> The following sections list the AWS regions in which Amazon SES is
>   available, and the corresponding endpoints for sending and receiving
>   emails.

Using the API (HTTPS) endpoint documented there, it shows the endpoint reference in EU (Ireland) as `email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. The endpoint formatted is the same in all regions. Therefore, the correct **ServiceName** for the `CredentialScope` is `email`

Answer (score 2):

The service name is ses
That worked for me (all lowercase).
You're right in that they don't seem to explicitly state that anywhere within their documentation!